# Unable to import .js file into Rockmongo with mongodb

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am using windows pc and my friend exported a mongodb collection form a mac into a .js(7 MB) file. When I try to import that file I get The connection was reset " The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your apache + php is the culprit. Perhaps the timeout is too short or the upload limit is too small.

Either way, I'd just use mongoimport directly. The full documentation is at  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Comment: I am sure the culprit is either php or apache

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue uploading a 3.7 M file with Rockmongo. It turns out my php.ini had the following (default) setting:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Changing that to

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

and restarting apache/php fixed it.